# Text vanishes and moves down on TextView because big size

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my English. I'm trying to keep my text on TextView but he moves down when I set big size. I have set android:gravity="center|left". When size is small there isn't problem. It looks well.

[text small size](http://s23.postimg.org/wmjvz071n/image.png) (sorry I cann't post images)

Unfortunately if I set size bigger text moves down.

[text big size](http://s7.postimg.org/hkzi7gj17/image.png)

Also text vanishes if I increase size more .
1)How can I prevent text moving?
2)How prevent text vanishing?

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/fragmentDialogPad" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textSizeET"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

    </EditText>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/textSizeSB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="500" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/okay" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sampleTV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="Sample" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could post your xml file ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the layout_height and layout_width to wrap content . If the problem still occurs after doing so maybe there is not enough space in our layout for your textview . It would be helpful if you post your xml. And also gravity should be android:gravity="center_vertical|left".

I am putting my version of xml that should work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:padding="0dp" >
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textSizeET"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >
</EditText>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/textSizeSB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="500" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="okay" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="cancel" />
</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sampleTV"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="150dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:text="Sample" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:gravity="center_vertical|left" doesnt help :(. See my xml file.

Comment: @Argamidon I think your fragmentDialogPad is may be high. Try reducing it. Also I cannot access the screenshots you have posted. You should consider using scollview if your content is too much for the screen.

Comment: I have just updated links of images. @dimen/fragmentDialogPad is 0dp.

Comment: @Argamidon I have just updated my answer. Please check whether that works for you.

Comment: I have tried many combination but it doesnt work, I have enough for this. Thank U for help. I am going to use this as is.